# How should I compile html templates with Gulp in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-ui-router

I have following directory structure in my AngularJS application:

```
|-app
|--blog
|---BlogController.js
|---BlogService.js
|---BlogResource.js
|---states.js
|---templates
|----blog.html
|----blog-post.html
|----edit-blog-post.html
|--user
|---UserController.js
|---UserService.js
|---UserResource.js
|---states.js
|---templates
|----user-info.html
|----user-update.html
|-dist
|--js
|---all.js
|-templates
|--blog
|---blog.html
|---blog-post.html
|---edit-blog-post.html
|--user
|---user-info.html
|---user-update.html
```

`app` folder is for develompment, `dist` folder is for production. I use Gulp for building project. `state.js` files contain ui.router states configutation. Here is example of this file:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('blog-post', {
        url: '/blog-posts/:id',
        templateUrl: 'blog/templates/blog-post.html',
        controller: BlogPostController
    })
}]);
```

Problem is in `templateUrl` property. When I build project actual place of all files changes and `templateUrl` doesn't point at html file. So `templateUrl` property must be changed in `all.js` file. How can I accomplish this with Gulp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this, in my opinion, is to use Angular's [template cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache). There is a gulp plugin called [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) that can help generate this output.

For example, say the contents of your `blog/templates/blog-post.html` are:

```
<h2>{{ :: blog.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ :: blog.content }}</p>
```

You could have a gulp task like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var angularTemplateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');

gulp.task('templates', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin())
        .pipe(angularTemplateCache('templates.js', {
            module: 'YOUR_ANGULAR_APP_NAME',
            root: ''
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

That will create a file `dist/js/templates.js` with this content:

```
angular.module('YOUR_ANGULAR_APP_NAME').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {$templateCache.put('blog/templates/blog-post.html','<h2>{{ :: blog.title }}</h2>\n<p>{{ :: blog.content }}</p>');}]);
```

All your templates from `app/` will end up that file, and any call to `templateUrl` will be able to find the correct template.

This solution solves the problem of your broken `templateUrl` links, and also it reduces the number of requests the client's browser has to make. You could also take that a step further and combine `templates.js` with your `dist/js/all.js` so that there is only one JavaScript file.